# Don't create git pre-commit hook

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

Inside my `package.json`I have `"pre-commit": ["lint"]`. Can I run `yarn install` such that the pre-commit hook isn't created?

Comment: what do you mean by *pre-commit hook isn't created*?

Comment: @antzshrek when I run `yarn install`, it creates the file `.git/hooks/pre-commit`. I'd like to skip that step for my local setup (I don't want to remove the `"pre-commit": ["lint"]` from `package.json` since other devs are using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moment you already have

```
  "husky": {
      "hooks": {
          "pre-commit": "lint"
      }
```

in your `package.json`, whenever you run `yarn install`, yarn pulls the info from `package.json` and install what are available, so I advice if you really wanna make your installations without  it creating the file in `.git/hooks/pre-commit`, you might have to remove `"pre-commit": ["lint"]` from `package.json`.

---

If your problem comes from when running `git commit`, you can might want to use

```
git commit --no-verify

-n  
--no-verify
```

> This option bypasses the pre-commit and commit-msg hooks. See also [githooks(5)](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

You can get more look from [git-commit(1) Manual Page](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html)

I hope is helps.

Comment: Upvoted because you mentioned `--no-verify`. This is the workaround!